# Check if column exists in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
for (int i = 0; i < completeInfoMatches.Count; i++) {
    if (!(databaseGridView.Columns.Contains(e.Node.Parent.Text))) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Node.Parent.Text);
        databaseGridView.Columns.Add("column" + i, e.Node.Parent.Text);
    }
}
```

If the column has the name already, I do not want it to be added.

My code seems like it would work, but for some reason it doesn't?

Comment: Wrong column name ???

Comment: Are you confusing the Name of the column with the HeaderText?

Comment: @Steve. I was lol Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `e.Node.Parent.Text` string refers to the `HeaderText` of the column not to the Name property. If this is the case then the code to find if an HeaderText exists with the same value of your e.Node.Parent.Text is the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < completeInfoMatches.Count; i++) 
{
    if (!(databaseGridView.Columns
              .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
              .Any(x => x.HeaderText == e.Node.Parent.Text))) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Node.Parent.Text);
        databaseGridView.Columns.Add("column" + i, e.Node.Parent.Text);
    }
}
```